# What are advantages of 1's complement over 2's complement in DSP?

Tags: computer-architecture, dsp, vlsi

I wanted to  know about the advantages of 1's complement over 2's complement in DSP applications.

Comment: Did you read [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement)?

Comment: Yes I did read it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to say sir?

Comment: We have no way of knowing what kind of "major reason" you're after. Closing as unclear.

Comment: One's complement has one advantage: it works regardless of endianness. That's why it's used in calculating TCP header checksum. Unfortunately this was closed so I can't post a more detailed answer

Comment: for some more details read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914479/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1's complement, changing sign can't fail, contrary to 2's complement. This mimics Floating Point, and remove one (minor) headache when moving FP algorithms with fixed point arithmetic, a common thing with DSPs.

To be clear: with 1's complement, it holds that if *x*<0 then (-*x*)>0, something that holds for FP but does *not* hold for quite all *x* with 2's complement, and easily bites when doing digital signal processing. DSPs aim at FP compatibility for their non-FP operations, and avoiding that corner case has some functional value.

Also: changing sign in 1's-complement reduces to complementing all bits; and thus, as noted in comment, it is endian-neutral. By contrast, changing sign in 2's complement requires carry propagation from low-order to higher-order chunks (byte, word, unamit).

I know no better reasons. Most other things (including signed addition and multiplication) are easier with 2's complement: in particular, the result (except status bits) is the same as for unsigned. That's why it won for the non-FP part of most modern processors, which support both signed and unsigned.

Comment: I need a major reason sir.

Comment: That is a good reason.  Why do you need a "major reason"?

Comment: I don't know the advantage in DSP but it has an advantage in network transmission because it doesn't depend on endianness, therefore it's used in TCP header checksum